# Should a user suspended on the main site be allowed to chat on associated chat-rooms?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, account-suspension

> Related: [Make it possible to revoke write access to public chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135734/make-it-possible-to-revoke-write-access-to-public-chat-rooms), [Don't extend suspensions from the parent site to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145235/dont-extend-suspensions-from-the-parent-site-to-chat)

Recently I came across a case where a user who was banned on a site was harassing a certain user (who was involved in the related meta post) in the chat-room.

I chat-banned the user for an hour<sup>1</sup>, but it led me to wonder why we don't suspend users from the related chat by default.

Note that, if the chat parent is suspended, the chat account is also suspended for the same duration. So in some cases, the chat ban may propagate automatically, and in others, it may not. As to *when* it propagates, that's pretty random as it depends on that particular user's chat parent (which is not always the same site). It seems strange to me that certain users lose chat privilege with a ban, and some don't, on a (more or less) luck based process.

I'm personally averse to propagating the ban to chat because I'm not sure if the user should be denied the right to chat elsewhere.

So, I have multiple questions:

- If a user who is banned from the main site for being disruptive in chat, is it okay to ban him for the same duration as main in chat? (I can change the parent user and force refresh to create this effect)
- In general, when should a ban on the main site be propagated to chat?
- Can we have a feature that bans a user from the related chat-rooms (and *only* those) if he is banned on a main site?

<sup>1. Because first offense bans in chat are usually for an hour or less. I wasn't sure what to do in such a situation so I kept it low. I was loath to propagating the ban to the chat because I wasn't sure if the user should be denied the right to chat elsewhere.</sup>

Comment: @dim nope. Unrelated chatroom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't extend suspensions from the parent site to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145235/dont-extend-suspensions-from-the-parent-site-to-chat)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't like the current feature that bans a user from SE chat when they are suspended on the parent site. It does not fit to the moderation policy which keeps a strict separation between the sites in terms of consequences, being suspended from one site has no effect on all the other sites.

It makes a certain amount of sense when you consider SO chat, but it falls apart on SE chat as there is no separation between sites in chat. It is also ridiculously easy to circumvent if you know about it.

I'd just remove the auto-suspension in chat entirely for SE chat (if that should also be removed for SO chat is something the SO mods should weigh in, but it should probably stay active there). But moderators should not hesitate to manually apply a chat ban of the suspension duration if a suspended users misbehaves on chat.

Comment: What sort of chat ban for disruptive users who are suspended on the main site? Light or heavy? (Heavy is measured in days). IMO it should be a heavy suspension if they're caught being annoying.

Comment: @Manishearth I'd go for the same progression as on the main sites, 7/30/365 days.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. I'll keep that in mind for the future. (I'd probably just re-link their chat accounts to their parent accounts; that lets the bas expire simultaneously)