# Chat shouldn't suspend me in rooms not associated with the site where I'm suspended

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, account-suspension

Chat has many problems.
[image]

(Wut? I'm not suspended here!)

I think chat should be redone. The URL is weird, sometimes its `chat.stackexchange.com` sometimes its `chat.SITE.stackexchange.com`.
Then here its `chat.meta.stackexchange.com` and the chat profile on other sites is not linked here.

I think we should use one site, and its `chat.stackexchange.com`.
That way, there's no funny suspension issues.

Instead, it should be like `chat.stackexchange.com/?site=SITE`.
Sites like stackoverflow will be just as the name is for SITE, not `chat.stackoverflow.com`.

Then for the suspension detection thing, it should not check the referrer, otherwise that ^ happens. Instead, it should look at the site for the room and check if the user is trying to chat.  and say "Hey! You're not suspended here! Chat!" or "Sorry, you're suspended. No chatting for you :(".
Also, the caching issue with SE 1.0 sites needs to be fixed.

Also, this makes all chat profiles one, not have multiple. Also, based on the site part of the URL, the CSS changes according the the site.

Here's how to get it.

1. Get a test account suspended.
2. Go to a room like `chat.SE.com/rooms/35/the-bridge`
3. Click "all rooms"
4. Go to a random room on a different site.
5. You're still suspended and can't chat.

This needs to be so that its not suspended on "chat.SE.com" but it checks on the site for the room. Example: I can't chat in Arqade rooms but I can chat in the charcoal chatbot sandbox room. Otherwise I can only chat on `chat.SO.com` and `chat.meta.SE.com`.

---

Ok if you don't like "redo" then lets go with "change some stuff"

Comment: Can someone explain why this is not a good idea? Or the downvotes?

Comment: You're basically saying "this is bad, scrap it and make a new one", but you don't appear to realize just how large of a task that is. You are basically grouping a bunch of feature requests into a single post. Also, I have yet to vote.

Comment: This isn't a feature request, it's a rant. And way too broad (so also voting to close as Too Broad). You can also say "the world is bad, let's recreate the world". Focus on single thing you think needs to be "redone" and suggest a feasible solution/alternative. Just throwing "it's bad, do it again" isn't helpful.

Answer (score 24):

Chat rooms do not exist in isolation. Behavior in one will frequently affect those in others. There are some protections afforded by separate domains, but within chat.stackexchange.com allowing a suspended user privileges to participate in (or even create) rooms would open the door to a great deal of unnecessary drama.

If you value the ability to participate in chat, then **stop getting suspended.** I guarantee you that the moderators on other sites - including this one - are no more likely to tolerate your antics than those on Arqade.

Comment: this talks about getting suspended on like maths chat se and so getting suspended on every chat se as opposed to like getting suspended on every chat se from getting suspended, like on maths parent se right? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199913/should-a-user-suspended-on-the-main-site-be-allowed-to-chat-on-associated-chat-r

Answer (score 17):

I agree with you on the structure not being exactly intuitive. Chat needs more love, new stuff *in general* - we shipped it *years* ago and it hasn't moved much since.

Now, if the *overwhelming* reason something is wonky is 'because the user is suspended', it becomes an *extremely narrow* use-case, and one that isn't likely to become a priority unless something is really blowing up.

Some of your suggestions are quite reasonable, and we'll keep them in mind when the time comes (others have indicated the url / domain schema to be confusing as well). However, we'll be looking at this when we want to look at chat itself, not because a suspension exacerbates an otherwise pretty trivial thing.

Answer (score 8):

There are three chats:

- chat.stackoverflow.com, allowing to create rooms only for Stack Overflow
- chat.meta.stackexchange.com, allowing to create rooms only for MSE
- chat.stackexchange.com, allowing to create rooms for any SE sites, **including MSE and SO**

If you are suspended on any site which has a domain of `*.stackexchange.com`, you can't use the last chat system, i.e. chat.stackexchange.com, regardless of referrer, **therefore the MSE room I created on chat.stackexchange.com can't be used by you currently**, but you chat in, for example, [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), because this room is created on the chat.**meta**.stackexchange.com.

Also, on the chat.stackexchange.com the rooms are already ordered by site, e.g.:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=gaming.stackexchange.com is for gaming.stackexchange.com.