# Prevent user banned on SE site from participating in that site's chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, ban

We have a case on Arqade where a user who is banned from the main site is still chatting in Arqade chat rooms, because his chat parent account was on a different site at the time of the Arqade site ban, and so wasn't affected by the ban. If his chat parent user was Arqade at the time of the ban, he'd have been banned from participation in all of chat for the duration of the site ban.

Instead of working this way, I think it would be nice if users who are banned from a specific site are also banned from participating in chat rooms specifically tied to that same site. So for example, the above user wouldn't be able to chat in Arqade chat rooms, but would be unaffected in other chat rooms.

I think this is cleaner than the current system of banning or not depending on the parent user at the time of the ban.

Comment: 0_o That... makes no sense. Are you sure it works that way now?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara We're dealing with it right now, he's not banned on chat despite being banned on the main site, so I'd say yeah it works that way now unfortunately.

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199913/should-a-user-suspended-on-the-main-site-be-allowed-to-chat-on-associated-chat-r?rq=1

Comment: @rene The answer there seems to be about banning on the entire SE chat for being suspended on a single site. My request is only to ban a user on that site's specific chat rooms when he's banned on a single site. Related, yes, but that question doesn't really cover my request.

Comment: Would it replace the current system? ... would a user with a parent site of Arqade who was suspended there be able to chat in non-Arqade chat rooms?

Comment: @Catija I could see that going either way, but I'd prefer they still be able to chat in rooms for other sites. A chat-wide ban would still be an option for users who are disruptive in general.