# Can you still chat if you change your parent site from where you are suspended to other site?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, profile-page, account-suspension

I have never been suspended from an SE site so I don't know, but let's say that I was suspended from X.SE, and that was the parent site for my chat profile, on my chat profile it would then say

> This user is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for xxx days

However, this suggests that if I were to then change my parent site for my chat profile that I would be able to chat again if my new parent site hadn't suspended me.

Is that so? Or would I still not be able to chat? And what about if my X.SE profile was suspended, would my chat profile also be even if I had set the parent site there as Y.SE?

---

Also, if changing their parent site wouldn't make a difference then the text about them not being able to chat *because* they have been suspended on their parent site is a bit misleading as it suggests that changing their parent site would enable them to chat again.

Comment: Related feature-request: [Don't extend suspensions from the parent site to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145235/dont-extend-suspensions-from-the-parent-site-to-chat)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The chat suspension is independent of the parent site suspension, despite the wording. Changing your parent site does not affect the suspension.

In other words, changing parent sites from a site you're suspended on to one where you're not doesn't lift the suspension.

> And what about if my X.SE profile was suspended, would my chat profile also be even if I had set the parent site there as Y.SE?

If you are suspended on X.SE while your parent site is still set to Y.SE, you will still be able to chat.

Your chat account will only be suspended *at the precise moment* that your parent site changes to X.SE (and for the exact remaining duration of the suspension).

(Note that moderators can manually change the user's parent site)

Comment: So changing parent sites from a site you're suspended on to one where you're not doesn't lift the suspension but changing from one where you're not suspended to one where you are imposes it?

Comment: @terdon Yep, exactly. (It's perhaps worth noting to future readers that moderators do have the ability to change a user's parent site.)

Comment: I think that it's a bit odd that if you change your parent site (if you have suspended on the current parent site) to another which you have not been suspended on it doesn't make a difference to your suspension from the chat site, but if you have it set to a parent site where you are not suspended, that then changing it to one where you are makes you suspended on your chat profile... Why exactly is it like this?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Why is that odd? Otherwise, it would be ridiculously easy to evade a chat suspension caused by a main-site suspension.

Comment: @Doorknob: No, I don't mean that way, I think it would be better if when you become suspended on one site, for it not to allow you to chat no matter which parent site you have set there, nor which you change it to.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Why? Main-site offenses (for example, posting excessive amounts of extremely low-quality questions, or abusing edits) do not always extend to chat. And when they do... moderators do have certain abilities hinted at in my reply to terdon.

Comment: So what if I posted many low-quality posts on AU and got banned from there, if that does not extend to chat then why do I get the ban there too if AU is my parent site for chat? I think that this is a strange way of doing things and rather than this you should give the mod who banned them (if they are banned by a mod and not the system) the option of whether they also want them to be banned on the chat site no matter what the parent site is set to there. Because if I post low-quality posts, then why do I only not get banned from chat too if a different parent site is set there?