# Could we get better ways to communicate and apply suspensions on chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, moderation, chat-ban

Chat suspensions are... strange. There's two ways to boot someone off chat - using a suspension on the parent account that's associated with the chat account (And [otherwise it's not global](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295395/could-we-tie-site-suspensions-to-chat-suspensions-globally))

Suspending someone only on chat has a few quirks on its own - we have no way of actually privately informing a user where they went wrong (and as someone who helps moderate a few other site chats, that's a pain), for some inexplicable reason we set suspensions by the hour. It's probably easier to set a site suspension if you're a moderator on the user's chat parent (or you reparent them), but misbehavior can be chat only.

While I realise chat isn't a priority right now, could we consider having moderator messages of some sort and by day, not per hour suspension options?

Comment: I might be missing something really trivial here, but what about private chat room? Just create a private room with the user and explain why you suspended. No need for extra tools as far as I can tell. The user won't be able to reply on chat, but they will be informed of the reason. Anyway "not per hour suspension options" is good point, sounds like clumsy thing indeed that better be improved.

Comment: Its inconsistent and manual. People forget too.

Comment: Also, @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar, that removes the anonymity of a moderator message.

Comment: @Mithical heh yes now that's a fair point. But still, developing whole new system for chat sounds.... too much. Maybe "merge" the mod tools for chat and main site profiles.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar another reason is that if you suspend someone, they can't answer so a private room, unlike a moderator message, doesn't give the user the chance to offer a defense. Also, asking a mod to actually go and engage in a live conversation with a disruptive and now probably quite irate user is putting quite a lot of weight on the mod. Some of the people we suspend are really unpleasant and not someone you'd like to chat with. So a private room can work in some cases (at least as a way of giving an explanation), but not always.

Comment: @terdon I agree, as for mod privacy, guess it's not hard to create new account e.g. "Meta Stack Exchange Moderators" and use it for such things, but meh, the other points are also valid.