# Paginate the Access List on chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

The reason should be clear enough, **[but if it isn't, here's a nice DoS page against Stack Overflow :D](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17/javascript?tab=access)**

Seriously though, this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: Or simply fix the issue of not being able to ban certain users from rooms.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yeah, or that.

Comment: Honestly, I think the "gallery room to prevent only a handful of people from talking" thing is terrible, and shouldn't ever be the case. I can't think of a single other scenario in which the access list would get long enough to need pagination.

Comment: I clicked the link and my browser almost crashed.

Comment: @FEichinger So do we, but unfortunately it's the only option.

Comment: @SomeKittens My point is that we should be curing the illness itself, not just the symptoms ;)

Comment: @FEichinger I'd love that, but balpha has already said it was nigh impossible: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135792/179812

Comment: @FEichinger We (JS room) totally agree with "gallery room to prevent only a handful of people from talking" is terrible. It's terrible, and we really really hate it. We don't feel easy with it at all. However, there is really little you can do when certain users abuse the system over and over. Regular flags are broken since [they don't carry context](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203346/) , mod flags require a mod to be present. Having people spam the chat for 30 minutes straight without being able to react is damaging our community and is frustrating. we only restort to it then.

Comment: Not to mention that users are usually warned several times before being muted, as well as communal consent.