# Comment link becomes invalid if question title changes

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

While viewing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242538/) answer, I noticed that the link to the comment was broken because the title of the question was changed. So I [updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/242538/revisions) the link. The link to the question should remain valid, even if the question title was changed. At least because links (long links) to questions and answers do not become invalid if question title was edited.