# How was the user able to address me in the chat when I did not even have the reputation to chat and was not there in the chat?

Tags: support, chat

How was the user able to address me in the chat when I did not even have the reputation to chat and I was not there in the chat ?

https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2777922#2777922

Comment: Please let me know if I am wrong, I will delete the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed you appearing as well in the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) yesterday so I assume you or a rogue script in your browser must have loaded the chatrooms in a tab.  Due to your low-rep it showed the ['anonymous'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239291/158100) avatar (this was implemented for some sad reasons)

Although you can't *speak* in the rooms, you can enter them. Users with enough rep can ping any user in the room which was technically the case for you at that moment. And that enabled @ShadowWizard to address you.

You can use the following script to get a list of users in chat:

`CHAT.RoomUsers.all().forEach(function(t){console.log(t.name)});`

If you enter a room you would see your username in the list as well.

Comment: `Due to your low-rep it showed the 'anonymous' avatar`, So how was the user able to correctly address with my name ?

Comment: It does 'know' your name. The avatar is anonymized because it was abused by some weird users that used offensive avatars. I've added a small script that shows the usernames that are pingable

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am amazed how my question was voted up ?