# Extend profile hiding in chat for suspended users

Tags: feature-request, chat, account-suspension, profile-picture

When a user is suspended, their account is reduced to 1 rep and all of his privileges are stripped. However, they can still join chat rooms.

This leads to various forms of possible abuse (all of which I've seen by suspended users):

- Join/leave spams
- Expletives in profile messages
- Hold one sided conversations with users of the room via [profile message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LvXA.png)

Suspended users cannot be kicked, and even moderators can do very little (aside from completely removing the account, which is often overkill).

My proposal is to extend [profile hiding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239291/166899) for suspended users to one of two levels:

- Prevent them from being shown in the user list at all.
- Strip their profile profile picture *and description* from the profile view visible from chat rooms (not from profile pages).

Comment: +1 but I've already written a userscript to ignore joining events of suspended users I really don't care about.

Comment: Sounds good to me although I think hiding them from the user list might be enough.

Comment: I tend to agree. But the last feature request asked for that, and they decided not to do it. Different circumstances tho

Comment: +1 This isn't always an issue, but every once in a while, when it is, it can be pretty problematic. Would like to see this implemented sooner rather than later.

Comment: No response so far. I recently encountered one such profile with offensive text in in it's 'About me'. Had to flag one of his posts to point out a problem which had nothing to do with his post and could've been avoided if your feature was implemented.

Comment: [3 years later...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364951/1014587)

Comment: @Mast [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without/306398#306398)